# MS VS 2010: change language settings from de to en

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, localization, upgrade

recently i have installed MS Visual Studio 2010 Professional as an upgrade from 2005.
I wanted to use the english version but after installation it's german(2005 was english if that matters).

I tried to change it via Extras/Options/Environment/[International Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kycbhy5d.aspx) to `"Same as Microsoft Windows"`(what is english) and restarted IDE (and system) but the change was not applied at all. There are only two options: german and *same as windows*.

### Facts:

- MS Visual Studio 2010 professional(upgrade from 2005 Professional) **german**
- OS is Windows XP(english)
- german is default input language(control-panel/regional.../languages/details), changed but without any effect

Did i miss something in the setup of the installation or do i have to install a language-pack?

---

**Edit:**
i have tried Rob's suggestion to deinstall Visual Studio and all of its components, install the english .net 4.0 framework and reinstall Visual Studio, but unfortunately without the desired result. It is german again with no chance to switch to english. The installation routine seems to overwrite the framework and replaces it with the [DEU-languagepack](http://www.microsoft.com/germany/net/net-framework-4.aspx).

Is it really impossible to change the IDE language-settings without installing an english version first? Is it at least possible to get english error-messages from the framework?

By the way, am i the only person that wonders why i need an english version first to be able to switch languages? Why should i then order any other language than EN at all?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What language is your VS2010 upgrade? Was it bought as an english or german version?

Comment: It should be english, but i'm afraid that it's german. While installation i see that .Net Framework DEU gets installed. I think we had some communication problems in our IT. Isn't it possible to change it to EN even if it's installed as DE?

Comment: Not as far as i know. As stated on on MS-website (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7ee0d8a7-32fb-407d-a010-da3a7d93fc2f) there are language packs available, but they only work on versions installed as english

Comment: Perhaps you could removing the entire installation including the .net framework. Then download an english installation of the .net4 framework, install it and after that install VS2010 and see what happens. Not sure if it will work, just an thought.

Comment: Maybe these 2 blogposts also help; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/03/24/560579.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/07/19/671825.aspx

Comment: uninstall all, re-install all: the good old Microsoft way of solving problems :)

Comment: I tried to change VS Language on my computer (hungarian windows, english VS) but nothing happened. (changed from English to "same as windows", which should be hungarian. An alert displays about the need to restart VS, but nothing changed after restarting.)

Comment: Most likely your upgrade package was german. This why your regional settings have changed along.

Comment: You found a solution to this?

Comment: @Rob: things may take longer, alone deistalling visual studio took 2 hours. Now its deinstalling .Net Framework4 extended, after this there are 4.0 client profile and de-language pack etc. to deinstall. I will give feedback.

Comment: Even if it will work, it's so time consuming to deinstall vs 2010 inclusive all other components(Entity framework,MVC2,Framework,etc.) and install them later again, that i would appreciate an alternative very much. The deinstallation takes longer than the installation!

Comment: I agree that it's a lot of work. I take it it isn't an option to return the wrong version to your IT-department?

Comment: @Rob: the question is if microsoft would still exchange this version to an english version and it seems that the answer is NO (what i've heard from IT).

Comment: @Tim Hopefully a solution will be found then. Maybe you can make an image if the solution I provided works out. Could save you a lot of work.

Comment: @Rob: After i installed english framework and reinstalled Visual Studio 2010, i got the german version again with no chance to select english :(

Comment: @Tim. Hmz...and how about the 2 links to the blogposts is gave you?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's possible.

Install your version (German). Once the installation is finished you can install the English trial version: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Trial - Web Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=26bae65f-b0df-4081-ae6e-1d828993d4d0&displaylang=en)

Once the trial installation is finished you are able to switch languages in

```
Tools -> Options... -> Environment -> International Settings
```

You can even uninstall the german version through appwiz.cpl. Look for Visual Studio components with de or DEU endings.

It seems that the license is language independent.

Comment: Anyone tried this way? I've a similar problem with the Italian version

Comment: Half-working: In English Win7, installed Visual Studio 2010 Japanese, then Visual C# Express 2010, changed the setting, and now I have a mixed-languages Visual Studio for C#. Some menus contain both Japanese and English. Better than nothing :-)

Comment: The link target is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and do the following

- Try to remove the VS2010 installation and the .NET framework installation. Then download the english version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en). Install the English .NET framework and then install VS2010.
- If that doesn't work then maybe the
  two blogposts below will help. There
  are tricks with startup parameters to
  be able to use a certain language.

  [Blog 1 about how to use the LCID
  parameter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/03/24/560579.aspx)

  [Blog 2 with a list of available
  language codes](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en)

Two other interresting blog posts from the same writer can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/03/11/549592.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/03/07/545919.aspx).

Comment: As i've mentioned in the comments, this unfortunately dosn't work because the VS-Setup will install the german language pack for 4.0 framework. So i don't see any way to get Visual Studio to speak english with the german version. Vice versa it should be not problem(have the en-version and install de language pack). But i can't exchange this version anymore(wholesaler).

Answer (score 0):

Install the English language pack over it and then open the file location where you have installed the visual studio and delete the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - DE folder leaving only Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU folder.