# Change chinese Visual Studio 2010 to english

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MS VS 2010: change language settings from de to en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780994/ms-vs-2010-change-language-settings-from-de-to-en)

My interface is in Chinese. Is it possible to change to English?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone had more-or-less this same problem here: [MS VS 2010: change language settings from de to en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780994/ms-vs-2010-change-language-settings-from-de-to-en) and they got it worked out for them.  I'd try looking into the accepted answer's suggestions.

Comment: There aren't any solution there. Thank you.

Comment: There is now a more-or-less working solution there.