# Change Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate from German to English?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to change my Visual Studio 2010 installation from German to English. However, I only have access to the German version (via [MSDNAA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic/bb250591)) for Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. How can I change it to English? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: One would think you could just go into the maintenance and set that as an option....

Comment: Under Programs and Features, however, my version specifically states *Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU*, which leads me to think you're going to have to get an English version of the DVD.

Comment: i have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - DEU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have multiple spoken languages inside of Visual Studio you must install multiple languages of Visual Studio. For each language version of Visual Studio you installed you will get another option in the Interantional Settings menu.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246590.aspx) for more info.

Comment: so i need to buy the english version?

Comment: I hope you didn't get a *Great Deal* on this from someone on eBay.

Comment: Yea, I believe you need to purchase the English version

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a non-English machine to try this on but Tools | Options | Environment | "International settings" has a "Language" setting.  On my system, the two choices are "English" and "Same as Microsoft Windows".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the solution that works for the Professional version?

[MS VS 2010: change language settings from de to en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780994/ms-vs-2010-change-language-settings-from-de-to-en)

It might work for Ultimate as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30681
Download a language pack from here, install it and then you can change to that language by clicking Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings.